# Large ecommerce sites that are built on drupal

Tags: ubercart, commerce

I'm having trouble trying to convince the team to adopt Drupal commerce/Ubercart.
Would anyone know of some large websites that are built on Drupal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Dries' list http://buytaert.net/tag/drupal-sites

Answer (score 4):

Drupal Commerce sites:

- http://www.eurocentres.com/en
- http://www.commerceguys.com/customers/showcase

Ubercart  sites:

- http://www.topsite.com/best/ubercart

High profile sites:

- http://www.infomagnet.com/content/high-profile-high-traffic-drupal-websites

Government sites:

- http://govfresh.com/2010/02/5-government-sites-using-drupal-effectively-for-open-government-initiatives/

Comment: The infomagnet link has a `NSFW` website image.